# How to calculate median of column values satisfying two conditions in excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel table:

```
+-------------+--------------+
|   Type (C)  |    value(D)  |
+-------------+--------------+
| AAA         | 0000         |
| BBB         | 12004        |
| AAA         | 5675         |
| BBB         | 0000         |
| BBB         | 7880         |
| AAA         | 9563         |
| AAA         | 878          |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to have the median of the positive (greater than zero) values of type AAA.

I tried as:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(AND(C$2:C$6950="AAA",D$2:D$6950>0),D$2:D$6950))
```

It returns zero. The table has many greater than zero values, hence it should be something greater than zero. How to do this query?

Comment: you need an "else" condition, yoy have done if the following conditions are satisfied, then do this... but there is no "else"

Comment: But I do not have any operation for `else` case. I want the values greater than zeros to have their median. Then how to add a blank case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the AND command here, it doesn't work, instead multiply the two boolean sections together. This will achieve the same thing as AND.

```
=MEDIAN(IF((D$2:D$6950>0)*(C$2:C$6950="AAA"),D$2:D$6950))
```

Press Ctrl, Shift, Enter to put the formula in. For the data given, I got a median of 5675.

If the 'numbers' in Column D are stored as strings, you need a different version of the formula to cope with the conversion

```
=MEDIAN(IF((D$2:D$6950<>"0000")*(C$2:C$6950="AAA"),VALUE(D$2:D$6950)))
```

Comment: No. There are three numbers which fit the criteria, 5675, 9563 and 878. The median of these is 5675

Comment: @Dipto_Das What value do you get with the formula I've given?

Comment: sorry, I did not press ctrl+shft+enter that time. Thanks.